# How are mongo documents treated with console.log?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my node.js script, I have a part that goes :

```
collection.find(options,function(err,results){
  results.each(function(err,doc){
    if(doc){
      console.log("");
      console.log(doc);
      <stuff>
    }
    else {
      <more stuff>
    }
  });
});
```

The two `console.log` lines display the line break and the json document correctly, but if I do it in one line with `console.log("\n"+doc)` it doesn't work as planned, it displays `[object Object]` instead.

Why is that ? I remember having trouble displaying documents the way I wanted sometimes, and understanding what happens here would help me use it better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do if I want to see it's state at the time it was logged is I just convert it to a JSON string. So...

`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));`

To...

`console.log("\n"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc)));`